# JSON строку в ассоциативный массив JS

Tags: массивы, json, javascript, парсер

Я постил раньше, но почему то проблема стухла.
Допустим, у меня есть переменная формата JSON, для примера возьмем с 3 группами элементов

```
var json ='{"login0":"11","la0":"48.30369","lo0":"38.033502",
"login1":"12","la1":"48.40369","lo1":"38.033502",
"login2":"13","la2":"48.70369","lo2":"38.033502"}';

Выполняя парсинг все работает корректно
var a = JSON.parse(json);
var b = a.login0;
var c = a.lo2;
document.write(b+c); // Выдает 1138.033502  - все ОК!

Вопрос, как сформировать массив вида:
[{login0:11, la0:значение[0], значение[0]}, 
{login1:12, la1:значение[1], lo1:значение[1]}, 
{login2:13[2], la2:значение[2], lo2:значение[2]} 
.... 
{login(i):значение[i], la:значение[i], lo:значение[i]}]
```

Comment: Здесь я понимаю что нужно сделать массив объектов, прошу помочь реализовать это

Comment: скажите тому, кто вам дает эту json строку, чтоб он дал вам правильную строку. изначальная строка у вас была лучше, надо только сделать ее в виде массива, а не плоского списка полей. то, что вы пытаетесь сделать сейчас - костыль.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov какого массива? У него индексы строковые.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 предыдущий [вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/262076/javascript-создать-объект-из-json-строки) посмотрите. с тем, что получится в частности в результате вашего ответа на этот вопрос, работать будет нельзя, точнее будет только хуже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/C69yX/

```
var json ='{"login0":"11","la0":"48.30369","lo0":"38.033502", "login1":"12","la1":"48.40369","lo1":"38.033502", "login2":"13","la2":"48.70369","lo2":"38.033502"}';

var parse = JSON.parse(json)
,   array = []
,   count = 0
,   once_element = {};

for(var obj in parse) {

    once_element[obj] = parse[obj];

    if(count % 3 == 2) {
        array.push(once_element);
        once_element = {};
    }

    count++;
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: это они должны по порядку идти, а в обжекте в каком порядке идут свойства?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 строковые ключи в том виде, как присваивали. Численные да, в каких-то браузерах всегда первые идут.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Тут можно почитать что порядок не определяется никак, могут идти в любом порядке. Так не надо делать.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 стандарт да, не дает определения о порядке. Браузеры же придерживаются того, что я написал комментарием выше.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 но я соглашусь, что ваш способ лучше, т.к. сработает 100%, даже при числовых ключах.

Answer (score 2):

Например так

```
var l = Object.keys(a).length/3;
var res = [];
for (var i=0;i<l;++i) {
    var k1 = "login"+i, k2= "la"+i, k3 = "lo"+i;
    res[i] = {k1:a[k1],k2:a[k2],k3:a[k3]};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась формированием корректной JSON строки вида:

```
var json
='[{"login":"37","la":"48.310736","lo":"38.043989"},
{"login":"399","la":"48.313092","lo":"37.973239"},
{"login":"140","la":"48.300127","lo":"38.017115"},
{"login":"1209","la":"48.308369","lo":"38.021465"},
{"login":"142","la":"48.308157","lo":"38.025267"},
{"login":"122","la":"48.331019","lo":"38.105643"},
{"login":"3129","la":"48.300707","lo":"38.020754"},
{"login":"3138","la":"48.34084","lo":"37.972458"},
{"login":"190","la":"48.334623","lo":"38.052168"}]';
```

Всем большое спасибо!