# Получение значения из .json файла

Tags: javascript, json

Как получить массив со значениями из .json-файла?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262130/json-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601494/convert-json-to-array-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array и т.п.

Comment: Где находится этот json файл?

Comment: ../json/json.json на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать [jQuery getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)